# Getting "Not Authorized" when using fuelsdk client

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication, fuel-sdk

I am doing exactly what the docs are saying:

`require 'fuelsdk'`

`client = FuelSDK::Client.new({client: { id: "myclientid", secret: "mysecret" }})`

`campaign = FuelSDK::Campaign.new`

`campaign.authStub = client`

`campaign.get`

with this I get a "Not Authorized" error. 
  why would that be?

ps. my application id is: 264268eb-2e49-4bb0-8ff4-5f3d0cc4761d

Comment: We are investigating this.

Comment: When the application was registered in App Center, what checkboxes were selected for Data Access?

Comment: What's the name of the app, I can check what they are as well.

Comment: Thanks Kelly for at least trying .. I would suggest fixing the code in the Client class to allow symbols or string hash keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh .. ok .. I finally figured this out. The designers of this api want you to go with string hash keys like so:

client = FuelSDK::Client.new({'client'=> { 'id'=> "myclientid", 'secret'=> "mysecret" }})

where I was using symbols.

It's very interesting because most ruby programmers would use symbols and not strings for hash keys and for a public api they would almost certainly allow both, since that would be the most obvious thing to do to avoid any issues like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you have set up your clientID and clientSecret properly, no stray spaces or mistypes?  It looks like what might be happening here is your credentials are incorrect.  The campaign object does not require specific permissions, and we are unable to replicate your issue.

I would investigate the clientID and clientSecret and verify they are 100% accurate.